# I want Notification for different times using alarm manager as passed in array by me in Android

Tags: android

so far I tried this , but my notification only works for the last time in array list. while I need notification for all times in array.

```
 int[]hour={5,11,18,18,19};
 int[]min={15,0,50,52,05};
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour[i]);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min[i]);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
                    Date date =calendar.getTime();
                    Notification2(date);
}
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private void Notification2(Date b) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver2.class);
        Random random = new Random();
        int j = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, j, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, b.getTime(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

MY Alertreciever class

```
public class AlertReceiver2 extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
        NotificationHelper2 notificationHelper2 = new NotificationHelper2(context);
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb = notificationHelper2.getChannelNotification();
        notificationHelper2.getManager().notify(m, nb.build());
    }
```

Comment: i thiink you are creating same object in loop  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); here you can initialize  this outside loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add [some flags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT) to your `PendingIntent` as last param, e.g. `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, j,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked for me .would it work if i set  my alarm manager repeating it daily?

`alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, b.getTime(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY ,pendingIntent);`

Comment: it should, but worth checking :) good luck!